# Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync call fails on Shared Mailbox

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

Version Affected:

- OfficeJS 1.1.38
- Mac Outlook 16.34 (20020900)

Note: This use to work before this Mac Outlook version

The following fails when called with a ***Shared MailBox*** (Works with individual mailbox)

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function(result) { console.log(result) })
```

Instead of getting a success with `itemId` the call fails with the following properties

- code: 5009
- message: “This browser does not support the requested API.”
- Name: “API Not Supported” status: “failed”

Comment: We are able to repro the issue. Thanks for reporting it. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.

Comment: We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available in upcoming builds. Depending on the release channel a customer is on, getting an updated build can take anywhere from 4-8 weeks.